# Get data from a specific column in the last row on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have a Google Form that inserts data to a Google Sheet and then a script in that sheet generates a number for that row. All the information is entered on the form except the number that's generated. I found a script that creates a PDF from that information, adds a QR code and emails it. The script uses a Google Doc for the template for the PDF. All of that works great but I need to find a way to get the number generated in the sheet so that I can use it to create the QR code.

I thought maybe I could use a script to pre-fill a box on the form with the last number on the sheet, but it doesn't seem possible with Google Forms. I then found some code that would grab the last row of a specific column, but I couldn't make it work with the existing code I'm using. Does anyone know of a way to do what I'm looking for?

The sheet looks similar to this:

```
|--------------|---------------|------------------|-----------------|
|    prefix    |     number    |    first_name    |    last_name    |
|--------------|---------------|------------------|-----------------|
|     AA       |     111       |    FExample1     |    LExample1    |
|--------------|---------------|------------------|-----------------|
|     AB       |     112       |    FExample2     |    LExample2    |
|--------------|---------------|------------------|-----------------|
|     AA       |     113       |    FExample3     |    LExample3    |
|--------------|---------------|------------------|-----------------|
```

The code I'm using:

```
// TJ Houston tjhouston.com (tj@tjhouston.com)

// Get template from Google Docs and name it

var docTemplate = "documentid"; // *** replace with your template ID ***

var docName = "label";

// When Form Gets submitted

function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Create number
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(row+5871); 

//Get information from form and set as variables

var email_address = "email@example.com";

var last_name = e.values[5];

var first_name = e.values[4];

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id

//var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)

var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)

.makeCopy(docName+' for '+last_name)

.getId();

// Open the temporary document

var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the document’s body section

var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template

copyBody.replaceText('key_LN', last_name);

copyBody.replaceText('key_FN', first_name);

// Insert barcode
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=" + prefix + "" + number + "&chld=L%7C1')
var totalElements = copyBody.getNumChildren();
var el=[]
for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
  var element = copyBody.getChild(j);
  var type = element.getType();
Logger.log(j+" : "+type);// to see doc's content
   if (type =='PARAGRAPH'){
   el[j]=element.getText()
   if(el[j]=='###'){element.removeFromParent();// remove the ###
     copyBody.insertImage(j, image);// 'image' is the image file as blob 
  }
 }
}  

 // Save and close the temporary document

 copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email

var subject = "Label for " + last_name + "";

var body = "Attached is the label for " + last_name + ";

MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file

DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);

}
```

Comment: This line`var body = "Attached is the label for " + last_name + ";
` gives Error: Unterminated string literal.

Comment: I think it should be  var body = "Attached is the label for " + last_name + "";

Comment: Thanks for all the help Cooper. I think I'm probably pretty close now.

Answer (score 0):

to get data from a specific column in the last row on Google Sheet which is your response form.
try this

```
function getlastdata(x){
  var s_ID = "1yLLsfU4tgR6_0Xny7CMjqKKALoHTrYLJybPyWHUwkQI"; //spreadsheet id
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(s_ID),
      s = sh.setActiveSheet(sh.getSheets()[0]),
      lr = s.getLastRow(),
      lc = s.getLastColumn();

  var obj = s.getRange(lr,1,1,lc).activate().getValues();
Logger.log(obj[0][x])
}
```

with :
the **s_ID** must be your *response spreadsheet ID* and **x** given as *num of specific column*